# How to get a value from map in kotlin?

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin

Is it possible to get the values in a map associated to a key, without using the key?

I have this code.

`val map = prices.associateBy({it.productName},{it.productPrice})`

which gives me this

`{Coffee=3.0, Gum=0.5, Beer=18.0}`

I want to be able to just grab all the prices (3.0, 0.5, etc.) and save them to a list.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here is the Kotlin document:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/values.html

You just need to operate the values function to the variable to get all the values from the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to get all the values from a map, you can just use the built-in `values` property on the map like this.

```
val map = prices.associateBy({it.productName},{it.productPrice})
val values = map.values
```

It returns a read-only Collection of all values in this map. Note that this collection may contain duplicate values.